# Laravel attach pivot data without errors

Tags: php, laravel

I a have pivot table and a relation on model Product:

```
public function product_bodies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(static::class, 'product_bodies')->withPivot('product_id', 'product_body_id');
}
```

In the controller when I want to attach data:

```
    $products = ['sadasdasd', 'asdasda', 'asdasd', 'asdasd']; //for column product_body_id
    $product = Product::create($request->all());

    $product->product_bodies()->attach($products);
```

I get the error:

> General error: 1364 Field 'product_body_id' doesn't have a default
>   value

If I do this:

```
public function product_bodies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(static::class, 'product_bodies', 'product_id', 'product_body_id')->withPivot('product_id', 'product_body_id');
}
```

Then all works well. But then I can't get pivot data with:

```
$product->product_bodies;
```

I get empty items..

How can I fix this problem?

Table `product_bodies` has 3 columns:

- id
- product_id
- product_body_id

In product_body_id I pass strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 3 ideas:

1. You need to replace static::class to '\App\ProductBody' or ProductBody::class

   ```
   public function product_bodies()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('\App\ProductBody', 'product_bodies')->withPivot('product_id', 'product_body_id');
   }
   ```
2. $products must be array of product bodies ids.

   ```
   $productBodiesIds = [1, 55, 66];
   $product->product_bodies()->attach($productBodiesIds);
   ```
3. Maybe, sync instead of attach will be a better solution.